# Wcf time out exception, occurs irregularly on one server

Tags: wcf, timeout

Error code:"
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:09:59.6320000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding."

This error occurs infrequently when calling a Wcf service methods. It doesn't matter what method is. I have created test methods that returns simple strings. Sometimes it times out, sometimes it works perfectly. The strange thing is that when the WCF service is published on one server(for testing purposes)- there is no timeout. When I publish it on another server(live/public) there occurs these timeouts infrequently. I have set the timeout to 10 min as you could see above.

The webconfig setting should be correct, because it works for the one server. The only change made is the ip address. I know this is very difficult to answer and a bit ambiguous.
I'm sure this problem is too high level for me to solve, or maybe I'm making a simple mistake and it is too obvious for me to notice. If you could give me a pointer or just friendly advice on this problem I would really really appreciate it. I am shooting in the dark here. I thank you for your interest, proved by you reading up to here.

Answer (score 0):

does it happen first time you call the service? if not, but does subsequently, it could be that the service instance has been locked by the calling thread - look into multiple instances or allowing concurrent use, obviously taking into account the thread safety requirements of your code

Comment: Thanx for the response. It happens at random. I think your suggestions will help me a lot.